# How to get people who have shared specific FB post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

It's easy to get people who have liked post: `https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552_10150189643478553/likes` 
How can I get people who have shared this post ?

Answer (score 1):

Using the Graph Explorer with a post that has shares:

https://graph.facebook.com/20531316728_10151733211311729?fields=shares

The output is:

```
{
  "shares": {
    "count": 1806
  },
  "id": "20531316728_10151733211311729",
  "created_time": "2013-02-10T12:59:25+0000"
}
```

Of course if you remove the `fields` parameter you see all the fields associated with that object.

**EDIT:** The post on Facebook - https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151733211231729&set=a.376995711728.190761.20531316728&type=1

Comment: yes, it provides the count of shares. But I need people ids who shared this post

Comment: I do not believe that information is exposed through the Graph API at this time. The alternative would be to scrape the UI but given you need to be logged in to view https://www.facebook.com/shares/view?id=10150189643478553 - it is likely to be more pain than it is worth.

Comment: FB uses load more, so you will need to scroll until the end of the page and only then parse HTML. It's impossible to get this list by curl